# Is it possible to make generic mapped object type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have two similar groups of typescript definitions:

```js
enum Operation1 {
  eof = 'eof',
  bof = 'bof'
}
type OperationConfig1 = { [key in Operation1]: TestBedConfig };

enum Operation2 {
  append = 'append',
  prepend = 'prepend'
}
type OperationConfig2 = { [key in Operation2]: TestBedConfig };
```

I can use them as following:

```js
const config1: OperationConfig1 = {
  [Operation1.eof]: { ... },
  [Operation1.bof]: { ... }
};

const config2: OperationConfig2 = {
  [Operation2.append]: { ... },
  [Operation2.prepend]: { ... }
};
```

I want to replace `OperationConfig1` and `OperationConfig2` with one generic type `OperationConfig` accepting `Operation` as a parameter in some form like

```
type OperationConfigGeneric<T> = { [key in T]: TestBedConfig };

const config1: OperationConfigGeneric<Operation1> = { ... };
const config2: OperationConfigGeneric<Operation2> = { ... };
```

The above code is invalid and throws following exception:

> TS2322: Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | 
>   symbol'.   Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.

**The question.** How can I parametrize mapped object type (OperationConfigGeneric)? Or is there any convenient alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but it is only possible when the type parameter T is something that can be a property key. So, if you declare T with PropertyKey as an upper bound, it works.

```js
type OperationConfigGeneric<T extends PropertyKey> = {
    [key in T]: TestBedConfig
};

const config1: OperationConfigGeneric<Operation1> = { ... };
```

Comment: This solution does not require additional `typeof`, which seems more convenient for end use.

Comment: @dhilt This is right solution (not only more convenient) because it maps over enum values (for some reason I though you need same keys as the enum has)